# Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control Windows Shell Extension for VS2019 azure devops server not working

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

This week our team upgraded from TFS to Devops Server.

I am unable to checkin files using the Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control Windows Shell Extension for VS2019.

Here's what I did.

I re-installed [the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtentionVS2019). After some wranging, I got it to connect to Devops server.

At first, I was getting the error "Team foundation server could not connect to the database. Verify that the server that is hosting the database is operational.". I found and edited or deleted files that referenced the old TFS server and rebooted. Then the context menu says "Azure Devops Server". Excellent.

The "workspace..." menu option brings up a window with correct settings.
The "get entire workspace" command works.
The "add..." command works.

But the "checkin...." command does not work. It doesn't post an error. Just nothing happens.

So two question:

1. Has anyone succeeded in using the shell extension with Devops Server?
2. Is there a generated log file somewhere that would have whatever is going on?

Comment: Just want to point out that all operations work. And I can "add" a file. But when I "check in", It never posts the dialog which asks for the checkin comment.

Comment: Have you tried adding a policy for check-in to make it required or have some condition like message length? I'd also see if another Windows user account with a different work space/environment is seeing the same thing. Is this only happening with the Shell extension/context menu? Does it also not work while in Visual Studio? I recall having weird issues like that when my old team moved DB servers and started playing around with policies.

Comment: It is only the shell extension having issues. VS Pro works fine. It had no issues before my company switched to Azure Devops. I am the only one on the team using the shell extension. I have no idea what is meant by "adding a policy".